# Passing data between views given that I am using instantiateViewController function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, instantiation

Basically I have five view controllers, the first one which is the initial one have two text fields whereby the user can enter values in them. Afterwards, based on the user selection from two picker views he/she will either be directed to the second, third, fourth or fifth view controller using the instantiateViewController function as soon as the Next button is hit. Thus, no segues have been used at all here.

What I would like to do is to:

(1) Transfer the data that the user entered in the text fields in the first view controller to either the second, third, fourth or fifth view controller depending on his/her selection to the picker views?

(2) When the user come back again from either second, third, fourth or fifth view to the first view. I want the data that he/she entered in the text fields to be retained?

I tried to use prepareforsegue and introducing segues between view controllers themselves rather than having them linked to buttons. However, things did not work out for me.

Any help on the above is much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Shadi.

Here is my code for the first ViewController which does not work:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var TextField: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func NextVC(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as UIViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromFirstToSecondVCSegue", sender: self)
    func prepareForSegue (segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        var DestViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

    }
```

}

}

Please advise on what do I need to do to correct it?

Comment: The values are retained in a Navigation Controller. Have you tried that? Otherwise you just use prepareForSegue to pass the data back to the initial View Controller.

Comment: When you instantiate the new view controller, you can pass the data simply by setting properties as you would in `prepareForSegue`. To pass data back you wil need to use a delegation pattern. Segues and unwind segues are better though. What were your problems?

Answer (score 1):

1) In you other(second, third, fourth or fifth) view controller have a property that you want to save e.g String

```
 class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

     var string: String?
  }
```

Then when in first view controller when you instantiate other view controller you can pass data like this:

```
otherViewController.string = "Some string"
self.present(otherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

2) If you present other view controller with present method i am 99% sure that text in text field will be saved. If not when you present other view controller save that data in UserDefaults and write it on viewWillApear.

Edit:

```
let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondViewController
nextViewController.yourPropertyInVC = dataYouWantToPass
self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note if you are not overriding prepare for segue method there is no need to call it.

Comment: NSUserDefaults isn't intended for passing data. A delegation pattern is a better approach.

Comment: @Paulw11 That is for second answer, saving data from text field, passing data is explained in first answer.

Comment: Yes, the first part is ok

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I am fairly new to coding can you please explain in more details how can I achieve this in my app?

Comment: Are you presenting other view controller with segue or in code?

Comment: Please Markicevic could you check my code in the above post and let know what do I need to do to fix it? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to transfer data from one view controller to another, but there are a few factors that influence which one to use.

For sensitive data like login/password information, use KeyChain. Otherwise, you could use UserDefaults (the SwiftyUserDefaults makes this very easy https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults), or create a singleton class and set your data in its properties.